# images from button press,images enlarged

Tags: android

new to android development and run into a hurdle,im making an app that will have a lot of pictures, what i want to achieve is after i have pressed a button in the main activity to take me to another activity, i would like a page full of buttons on this new activity that once pressed each button will show a image and have some text i would like to add, i would like to do this without having to create a new activity for each photo so i am hoping somebody could kindly help me with this! think of it like a sounbank app that plays a sound when the buttons from each row is pressed! in my case it will show an image for each button, could this be done with just the main activity and an extra activity or will i end up with an activity open in project explorer for each picture.
your help is greatly appreaciated thank you.

Comment: This sounds like it can be done with only two activies. But, although I hate it if newbs get downvoted without any comment, I also have to say that we need a bit more information's here to help you. Please specify what you really want (for example with a little mock up drawing) and tell us what you have done so far. Happy coding and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: hi jacksOnF1re and thank you for your reply, so far i have designed the ui on android studio and set up a onclicklistener for the button i want to use to take me to a menu of multiple buttons on another activity, it is this part i am having a problem with, i have a display full of buttons and i want to press each button to display a different fullscreen image.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the problem but if it's only showing a image full screen on the click of a button you can start a new activity in the onclick and then fill the screen with the image. A ImageView with height="match_parent" and width="match_parent"

Comment: R. Adang, thank you, would this work for all buttons in the onlick of the main activity?

Comment: and to do that would i set it like this for each button....
@Override    
public void onClick(View view) {        Intent i;        i = new Intent(this,);        startActivity(i);    }

Comment: R. Adangs approach is a nice way to begin. Think about to put the path or resource id into the extra bundle of your intent. intent.putExtra(key, "yourpath_or_id"); and to extract it back in the activity in onCreate(bundle saveInstanceState) -> saveInstanceState.getExtras

Comment: JacksOnFire brilliant, i shall have a try with this thank you

Comment: would i add the path as the drable folder that i placed the images in?
intent.putExtra(drawable image);
thanks a lot for your help guys i really appreciate this

Comment: Well, all your resources get an identifier if you build your app. This identifier is saved as an integer in your R. So you can just pass the id via putExtra(key, R.drawable.yourimagename); And extract it via .getIntExtra :)

Comment: hi jacksOnFire, i am at here with the code in my main activity, had prob with my image with the putExtra R,drawable, would this be placed in the middle of the view view as i get errors when try it so took it out! could you kindly diagram the position for me? 
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp_test);
        Button buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         }

Comment: sure, I will update an answer this evening or tomorrow. currently at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets assume you are using drawables from your resource folder.
In that way you deal with integer ids that represent the images.
These id can be transmitted per Intent to a second activity, that
retrieves the intent, parses the id and loads / shows the image.

In your Activity A, where you have all your buttons, I assume further that
you've added OnClicklisteners to the button like:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //something
            }
        });
```

In your click listener you replace *//something* with:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext, ActivityToShowImage.class);
    i.putExtra(ActivityToShowImage.IMAGE_KEY_SOME_STRING, R.drawable.oneOfYourImages);
    startActivity(i);
```

The first argument is the key to retrieve the id later and the second is the id.
The R.drawable.oneOfYourImages depends on which button got clicked and shoud
be different for every button.

You can do this for every button, or you create a method that returns an
OnClickListener with the id as parameter.

```
private View.OnClickListener showImageFor(final int resIdOfImage) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext, ActivityToShowImage.class);
            i.putExtra(ActivityToShowImage.IMAGE_KEY_SOME_STRING, resIdOfImage);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
}
```

Now, in Your ActivityToShowImage, you override the onCreate like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        int imageId = 0;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            imageId = extras.getInt(IMAGE_KEY_SOME_STRING, 0);
        }
        if(imageId == 0){
            //some log message or exception and don't forget to finish in onResume()
        }else{
            loadImage(imageId);
        }
}
```

And in your loadImage method you load the image via the id into an ImageView.
I hope that is the answer to your question and sorry for the late response.

Comment: JacksOnF1re sorry for late response i have been away, thank you for this you have helped solved a headache and i really appreciate it! thank you